# How do I trigger a reset password?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, asp.net-membership

I work in Microsoft .NET 4.0 environment.
In my application I enable the user to get new automatic password.
So I use in my .cs file the method:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
user.ResetPassword();
```

I want to trigger on reset Password, means: when the password is changed to the automatic
one, an email will be sent to the user's email address with the new password (that is returned from user.ResetPassword()).

I use standard Membership DB tables.

I wrote the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MembershipChangePass ON aspnet_Membership
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @user uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @email nvarchar(256)

SELECT @user = (SELECT UserId FROM UPDATED)
SELECT @email =(SELECT LoweredEmail FROM aspnet_Membership
            WHERE @user=UserId)

EXEC xp_sendmail @email, ??? 

END
GO
```

1. The problem is how do I get the ??? - the new automatic password I created by
   the method: user.ResetPassword();
2. Can I define the TRIGGER to be used only with user.ResetPassword(), and not with other 
   methods (like: (user.ChangePassword(...))?
3. Maybe there is another simple way to trigger reset password?

Thank you.

Comment: If the correct time to send email is defined by an event in your application (`user.ResetPassword()` is called), then the correct place to send the e-mail is in the application. Don't put application specific logic like this in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The `ResetPassword()` method returns the new password which you can grab and send to the user

```
string newPassword = user.ResetPassword();

string toAddr = "user email here";
string subject = "Password reset notification";
string body = "Your new password is "+newPassword;

//mail.Send(fromAddr, toAddr, subject, body);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems that triggers are not the way for handling this issue.